# Multiple cursors with Wacom and Wayland

Tags: cursor, wacom, wayland

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland. It is detecting my Wacom tablet and I can use it for free painting, but the pen does not take over the main cursor, so I can see 2 cursors.

Seeing them would not be an issue, but if I want to paint straight line in MyPaint for example, it automatically takes the second cursor as start of the line, which makes it impossible to paint straight lines.

Is there a way to disable the second cursor and have only one when I use the pen?

Answer (score 3):

Having two cursors when using a tablet in Wayland is [by design](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/5dylj0/fedora_25_wayland_wacom_as_primary_mouse_input/), but the problem you describe could be due to the fact that you're using X applications on Wayland (using XWayland). Tablet support for X applications under Wayland will be [included](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=XWayland-Tablet-Pads) in the upcoming Xorg 1.20, which will be released in 2018. Until then, you're better of using Xorg. Now, I don't know or use MyPaint myself, so if MyPaint is actually a native Wayland application, my answer does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I tried using my Wacom tablet the second cursor doesn't work - it was hidden or had an offset. After checking the Pre-released updates option under Developer Options tab in Software and Updates and after updating my packages I have only one cursor and everything seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Did not help. Only thing that works so far is to revert to X.org.